# get_comments_number() vs. get_post_field( 'comment_count', ID )

Tags: comments

When I want to show the number of comments a post has - and I'm within the loop - which function is recommended to use?

```
get_post_field( 'comment_count', get_the_ID() )
```

or

```
get_comments_number()
```

This is the `get_post_field` function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve data from a post field based on Post ID.
 *
 * Examples of the post field will be, 'post_type', 'post_status', 'post_content',
 * etc and based off of the post object property or key names.
 *
 * The context values are based off of the taxonomy filter functions and
 * supported values are found within those functions.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 * @see sanitize_post_field()
 *
 * @param string      $field   Post field name.
 * @param int|WP_Post $post    Post ID or post object.
 * @param string      $context Optional. How to filter the field. Accepts 'raw', 'edit', 'db',
 *                             or 'display'. Default 'display'.
 * @return string The value of the post field on success, empty string on failure.
 */
function get_post_field( $field, $post, $context = 'display' ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    if ( !$post )
        return '';

    if ( !isset($post->$field) )
        return '';

    return sanitize_post_field($field, $post->$field, $post->ID, $context);
}
```

And this id `get_comments_number`:

```
 /**
 * Retrieve the amount of comments a post has.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param int|WP_Post $post_id Optional. Post ID or WP_Post object. Default is global $post.
 * @return int The number of comments a post has.
 */
function get_comments_number( $post_id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        $count = 0;
    } else {
        $count = $post->comment_count;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    /**
     * Filter the returned comment count for a post.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param int $count   Number of comments a post has.
     * @param int $post_id Post ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'get_comments_number', $count, $post_id );
}
```

I can tell they have differences, but I don't understand which one is better (if at all. Maybe they're both ok).

Comment: They are pretty much the same. You really can't say one is better. One has a specific and the other one a more general purpose - that is it. Personally I tend to go with the specific ones, but that is only a personal preference. In summary, just chose which one you want to use.

Comment: Thank you. Since this answered my question, would you be so kind as to post it as an answer?

Comment: To add to @ialocin's comment, the latter also uses the filter `get_comments_number`, which some plugins like Disqus might use to intercept the value. With WordPress, the general consensus is: if a function exists for a specific purpose, use it, even if there are "other ways" to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are pretty much the same. You really can't say one is better. One has a specific and the other one a more general purpose - that is it. Personally I tend to go with the specific ones, but that is only a personal preference. In summary, just chose which one you want to use.

Addition from @TheDeadMedic

> (...) the latter also uses the filter `get_comments_number`, which some plugins like Disqus might use to intercept the value. With WordPress, the general consensus is: if a function exists for a specific purpose, use it, even if there are "other ways" to do it.